# How to pass state values from a component into another child component that contains param settings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I have a basic component that goes out and gets user info via axios and then sets the users state. But in the component, I have another nested component that is a form type component that sets placeholders, defaultValue, etc.

This is the lifecyle method that gets the data and sets state:

```
   componentDidMount() {
     axios.get('https://niftyURLforGettingData')
     .then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
       const users = response.data;
       this.setState({ users });
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
     });
   }
```

Nested within this component is my form component:

```
<FormInputs
   ncols={["col-md-5", "col-md-3", "col-md-4"]}
   properties={[
    {
     defaultValue: "I NEED VALUE HERE: this.state.users.id",
    }           
/>
```

if I use just:
{this.state.users.id} outside the component it works... but inside form...nothing.

I am quite sure I have to pass the state into this component... but can't quite get it.

Comment: Could you go into more detail as to what the issue is? `defaultValue: this.state.users.id` ought to be what you want, if it "doesn't work" then we need more detail as to what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it doesn't work because `users` is `undefined` when your component renders for the first time.
Try to initialize that variable in the state doing something like this:

```js
state = {
 users: {}
}
```

and then use a fallback since `id` will also be `undefined` doing this:

```js
<FormInputs
   ncols={["col-md-5", "col-md-3", "col-md-4"]}
   properties={[
    {
     defaultValue: this.state.users.id || "Fallback Value", // this will render "Fallback value" if users.id is undefined
    }           
/>
```

If this is not the case please share more information about your situation.